# how to avoid error: "CommandText property has not been initialized properly"?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

database is in the sqlYog,

> when i run this program i am getting the error:
>    **CommandText property has not been initialized properly..?**

please help me

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public dbconn As New MySqlConnection
Public sql As String
Public dbcomm As New MySqlCommand
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    dbconn = New MySqlConnection("data source= localhost; user id=root; password=search; database=bookstore;")
    dbconn.Open()
    dbcomm.Connection = dbconn

End Sub

Protected Sub btn_login_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click

    Try
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)

        sql = "select * from bookstore.lib_user where username=@username  and password=@password"

        dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt_username.Text)
        dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_password.Text)

        Dim dbadpt As New MySqlDataAdapter(dbcomm)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dbadpt.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("login is suceesfull")
        Else
            Literal1.Text = "invalid login"
        End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("read this error: " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the sequence of lines.

First set the query text then call the command constructor.

```
sql = "select * from bookstore.lib_user where username=@username  and password=@password"
dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code `sql` is empty when assigning to your `MySqlCommand`, You need to set the `sql` value first then assign it to your `MySqlCommand` object .

```
sql = "select * from bookstore.lib_user where username=@username  and password=@password"

 dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
```